# How To Determine What Input Bus Is Active When AUEffectBase::Render Is Called?

Tags: c++, audio, core-audio

It's clearly a n00b question, as this has been implemented successfully in applications. But it's 2009 and I'm still unclear how input/output buses work with `AUBase`.

I'll crib the wording of my question from [a post to the coreaudio-api mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2003/Jun/msg00205.html). This question [pops up other times](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2004/Nov/msg00166.html) with no answer through 2005.

I was just looking over the `AUBase` code again, and I'm having trouble seeing how `AUBase::Render()` is supposed to work in the case of multiple busses (because it doesn't take a bus number argument)...

Here's a quick overview of the method call order:

1. In the implementation of `AUBase::DoRender()`, the local variable `output` is set to `GetOutput(inBusNumber)`.
2. Then the `output` variable is eventually (after calling the pre-render notify callout) passed to `AUBase::DoRenderBus()`.
3. `DoRenderBus()` does some buffer preparation on `theOutput`, which is `output` passed in (for the given bus number), and then calls `RenderBus()`. The output element is not passed along.
4. The default implementation of `RenderBus()` calls `NeedsToRender()` and then onto `Render()`, without passing the bus number or output element object.

The comment above `AUBase::RenderBus()` in AUBase.h says:

> Override this method if your AU processes multiple output busses completely independently -- you'll want to just call `Render` without the `NeedsToRender` check. Otherwise, override `Render()`.

To me, the comment above sounds like it's saying that you should do your processing in `Render()` *even* *if* you support multiple busses.

So... if one does his/her processing within `Render()`, how is one supposed to determine which output element to work with? If you also override `RenderBus()`, you could store the `inBusNumber` argument somewhere for use in `Render()`, but that's just ugly.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, `Render` does not take a bus-number argument.

```
virtual OSStatus Render(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags & ioActionFlags,
                        const AudioTimeStamp & inTimeStamp,
                        UInt32 inNumberFrames);
```

I believe this means it should render output for all output busses. It will also fetch input from all input busses.

To determine which input busses exist/are connected/active (not sure what the terminology is) you can call `HasInput`.

I only tried it with one output bus and several input busses.

Comment: Still, if you have buses a,b,c connected, there is no way to tell when in Render() which bus is being rendered. As you point out you can know which buses are connected, but that still leaves a,b,c as possible callers of Render().

Comment: @Noel: You assume that a specific bus must be the caller of Render. imho this assumption is wrong and the audio engine calls Render to render the frames for specific times for all busses.